# transefer file from server to server using web services

Tags: c#-2.0

i have to make one .net framework 2.0 web services which took some parameters like source server name destination server name file name then this services will move the file from source to destination.
one solution i found is using asp.net i make two pages  one for file download and one for file upload and this pages are available at each server.
web services will send http request to the server and server will send file or save file on server.

but in this i have to place this two pages on all server.
Is ther any way in which i can read and write and create file from the remote server using web services in .net framework 2.0?
if any boduy know about it please help me.
sorry for spelling mistakes and grametical errors.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the account your web service runs under has sufficient permissions you could use paths like this:

```
\\servername\c$\somepath\somefile
```

Another solution would be to use UNC shares but you won't be able to read and write to arbitrary paths.

Comment: hi will you please tell which permission are need for access the remote server file
thanks

Comment: Any member of the local Administrators group.